# How to consult education rate for a specific animal?

Tags: planet-zoo

I'm in a Franchise game where small objectives give money reward. One challenge is to increase Yellow Anaconda education rate to 13%.

[image: Increase Yellow Anaconda education rating to 13%]

How can I access to the education rate for each of my animal types? I cannot see in the dashboard or in any tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the overall education rating, the education rating per species and other education related information by going to the "Zoo" tab in the bottom left corner, then selecting "Education" in the left bar. Hover over various items to see what they mean.

When you have such a goal, the current education rating is also shown near the goal itself in the Challenges screen.

[image: The "Per Species" tab in the education overview shows reached guests and education percentage per species]

To reach the goals, research the animal fully (using Vet Research), place education boards and education speakers, and place down information kiosks where people can buy audio guides.

Answer (score 0):

To increase Animal education you can go to **Facilities > Devices and Speakers > Select Education Speakers** make sure that you don't select Ambiance or Music speakers. Then choose the animal you want in your case the Yellow Anaconda. Then you can use the Guest Education view in Manager View to see the radius.

[Source](https://twinfinite.net/2019/12/planet-zoo-how-to-increase-education/)